# Customize Jersy Mustache Mvc

Tags: java, jersey, mustache

For some reason the instance of `DefaultMustacheFactory` created by Jersey is not suited for my need and I want to create my own instance like this instead of using the default one:

```java
DefaultMustacheFactory factory = new DefaultMustacheFactory();
factory.setObjectHandler(new ReflectionObjectHandler() {
  @Override
  protected boolean areMethodsAccessible(Map<?, ?> map) {
    return true;
  }
});
```

How can I tell Jersey to create the instance as above? I read the documentation of jersey (https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/mvc.html#d0e15510), found property `MustacheMvcFeature.TEMPLATE_OBJECT_FACTORY`, but I don't know how to use it.

Background: Jersey 2.13,Java 11, Mustache is transitive-dependency of Jersey.

Configuration:

```java
@ApplicationPath("/api")
public final class OnlineGlossaryApp extends ResourceConfig {
    public OnlineGlossaryApp() {
        // Jersey features
        register(MustacheMvcFeature.class);
        property(MustacheMvcFeature.TEMPLATE_BASE_PATH, "/template/");
        property(MustacheMvcFeature.TEMPLATE_OBJECT_FACTORY, "should.throw.error"); 
    }
}
```

For now I don't use `web.xml`, but in near future I think I will/must use `web.xml`.

Comment: How are you configuring your application, with a web.xml or a ResourceConfig (or both)?

Comment: with a ResourceConfig.

Comment: I think you need to pass an instance of the factory as the value of the property. Jersey will not create it. It will simply look it up via the property.